# Cannot import file in typescript

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angularjs-directive

I wanted to use a typescrypt function from another file, but there is a problem:

I made a file Module.ts with an

```
export function CustomDirective(): ng.IDirective {
    var directive: ng.IDirective = <ng.IDirective>{//Filling directive here
    };
    return directive;
}
```

In app.ts (same folder) I tried to import this file and use in

```
angular.module(...).directive('name', CustomDirective())
```

I tried to use

```
import 'Module';
import Module = require('Module');//
import * as Module from 'Module'; // this two with Module.CustomFirective();
```

But if there is an import, there accures an error that Module cannot be found. And PublicController, BusyIndicator become also not found.

How do I insert file with a function properly?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
import {CustomDirective} from './Module';
```